# Test EventKit calendar access

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, eventkit, ios6

I had to find out that my own app was never denied on my iPhone to get access to the calendar. But on all others I was missing the code for asking for permission.

Now i included the appropriate code, but how can I be sure it works without submitting it to the App Store?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the app and reinstall it onto your phone, your phone will treat it as a new application and it will ask for permissions again, such as access to the calendar.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that's not the way if you install it using xcode.
Using xcode the app automatically gets all rights.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy

on your test device.